# JAVA Apache POI and large result set from DB2 runs into exception

Tags: java, sql, excel, db2, apache-poi

I try to create from a result set an XLSX file with Apache POI. The data comes from a local DB2 instance. The table I am querying has 580,000 entries.

Everything goes well, if I query for example the first 15k of rows, but when I try to query for all rows I get the following exception and the file is corrupted when I try to open it in Excel.

I'm using Apache POI 4.0.0 and Java 1.8

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: This archive contains unclosed entries.
at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.finish(ZipArchiveOutputStream.java:467)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.injectData(SXSSFWorkbook.java:406)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.write(SXSSFWorkbook.java:936)
at exportexcel.ExportExcel.createXLSX(ExportExcel.java:110)
at exportexcel.ExportExcel.main(ExportExcel.java:137)
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\9.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 12 minutes 19 seconds)
```

The line the exception points to is `workbook.write(out);`

Below my code I'm using

```
package exportexcel;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ExportExcel {

private static final String FILE_NAME = "c://file.xlsx";

public static void createXLSX() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    workbook.setCompressTempFiles(true);
    SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("RawData");

    String url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/local";
    java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
    properties.put("user", "user");
    properties.put("password", "pass");
    Connection con;

    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        // Load the driver
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        System.out.println("**** Loaded the JDBC driver\n");

        // Create the connection using the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ
        con = DriverManager.getConnection (url, properties);
        // Commit changes manually
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("**** Created a JDBC connection to the data source\n");


        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT STATEMENT");

        System.out.println("**** Created JDBC ResultSet object\n\n");

        ResultSetMetaData rsMetaData = rs.getMetaData();

        int numberOfColumns = rsMetaData.getColumnCount();

        SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
        SXSSFCell cell;

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            cell = row.createCell(i-1);
            cell.setCellValue(rsMetaData.getColumnName(i));
        }

        int i = 1;

            while (rs.next()) {
               row = sheet.createRow(i);
                for (int j = 1; j <= numberOfColumns; j++)
               {
                   cell = row.createCell(j-1);
                   cell.setCellValue(rs.getString(j));
               }
            i++;
            System.out.println(i);
            }            // Execute a query and generate a ResultSet instance

        System.out.println("\n**** Fetched all rows from JDBC ResultSet\n");
        // Close the ResultSet
        rs.close();
        System.out.println("**** Closed JDBC ResultSet\n");

        // Close the Statement
        stmt.close();
        System.out.println("**** Closed JDBC Statement\n");

        // Connection must be on a unit-of-work boundary to allow close
        con.commit();
        System.out.println("**** Transaction committed\n");

        // Close the connection
        con.close();
        System.out.println("**** Disconnected from data source\n");

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_NAME))) {
            workbook.write(out);
            workbook.dispose();
            workbook.close();
            out.flush();
        }
        System.out.println("File written!");
    }

    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Could not load JDBC driver");
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }

    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.err.println("SQLException information");
        while(ex!=null) {
            System.err.println ("Error msg: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println ("SQLSTATE: " + ex.getSQLState());
            System.err.println ("Error code: " + ex.getErrorCode());
            ex = ex.getNextException(); // For drivers that support chained exceptions
     }        
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    createXLSX();
}
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which line is the one that's throwing the exception? What I find strange: why workbook.dispose() and where do you close out?

Comment: Have your proved that an XLSX can contain all rows if you *don't* use Apache POI?  In other words, narrow down where the issue is happening (e.g. in java heap, or in Apache POI library, or in your code etc).  In particular verify if you can create the xlsx manually from excel by importing a delimited file created by exporting all rows using the Db2 CLP export command.

Comment: @ Ralf - the line which throws the exception is "workbook.write(out);". The "workbook.dispose()" is for disposing the temporary files from the stream

Comment: @mao - I can create without any problems the full extract as csv and then import into Excel and save it. The strange thing is that I don't get the exception with a smaller amount of rows for example 15,000 rows, then the file is written without any problems.

Comment: Find the number of rows that triggers the exception, then debug the code in the workbook.write(). If you have a reproducible test-case, you might also open a ticket on the Apache-POI library.  You should also investigate whether increasing the java heap has any impact.

Comment: Might related to a 64bits bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62872